# why modifing a ionic 2 list using array of objects bindings does not work from a modal?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Please look at this plnkr example. When adding or deleting steps the list updates accordingly. Now click on any one of the items in the list to delete an item. This will open a modal with a delete button. After clicking the delete button the item is deleted from the array but display does not update anymore. After this the add and delete buttons no longer work. What am i doing wrong?

http://plnkr.co/EbbkZb

```
import {Page, Alert} from 'ionic-angular/index';
import {NavController,NavParams} from "ionic-angular/index";
import {Modal} from "ionic-angular/index";
import {ViewController} from "ionic-angular/index";


@Page({
    template: `
  <ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>Tab 1</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="page1">
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <button (click)="addStep()">Add Step</button>
  <button (click)="deleteFirst()">Delete Step</button>
</ion-content>

<ion-list inset>
 <button ion-item 
            *ngFor="#step of steps"
            (click)="editStep(step)" >
      <ion-icon name='planet' item-left></ion-icon>
      {{step.name}}
    </button>
</ion-list>

  `,
})
export class Page1 {

    private steps: any;

    constructor(private nav:NavController) {
      this.steps = [];
      this.steps.push({id: 1, name: "step1"});
    }

    editStep(step) {

        let modal = Modal.create(MyModal,step);

        this.nav.present(modal);

        modal.onDismiss(data => {

          console.log("on dismiss");
          console.log(data);

          var stepIndex = this.steps.findIndex(function(step){
            return step.id == data;
          });

          console.log("at index");
          console.log(stepIndex);

          this.steps.splice(stepIndex,1);

          console.log(this.steps);
        });
    }

    addStep(){
       let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6000) + 1;
       this.steps.push({ id: id, name: "step"+id});
       console.log("adding step with id " + id);
       console.log(this.steps);
    }

    deleteFirst(){
       if(this.steps.length > 0){
         this.steps.splice(0,1);
         console.log("after deleting first");
         console.log(this.steps);
       }
    }
}


@Page({
    template: `
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>MyMocal</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
        <button nav-pop>
            <ion-icon [name]="'close'"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-content padding>
    <button danger (click)="deleteStep()">Delete</button>
  </ion-content>`
})
export class MyModal {

    private step: any;

    constructor(private nav:NavController, private viewCtrl:ViewController, private params: NavParams) {
       console.log("my mocal constructor ");
       console.log(this.params.data);
       this.step = this.params.data;
    }

    deleteStep() {
        let confirm = Alert.create({
            title: 'Delete Step?',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Yes',
                    handler: () => {
                        console.log("deleting " + this.step.id);
                        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.step.id);
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'No'
                }
            ]
        });

        this.nav.present(confirm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using modal like this:

```
 constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

 }

 editStep() { 
   let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(MyModal,step);
   modal.present();
   modal.onDismiss(data => {

      //your rest of the code goes here

    });

 }
```

Comment: If I attempt to use ModalController instead of Modal, then i get this error:  **_EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Page1'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Page1' is decorated with Injectable_**    Is this because i am using a beta version of angular which does not include ModalController? I try using most recent versions but this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Deepak that was the issue. It worked after I added the proper references.